# Using piecewise and switch in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, piecewise

I'm totally new to MATLAB. I'm trying to define a function that helps in Gaussian Integration. The function should accept `n` (the number of points) as an input and return the values of the points, `pG`, and the associated weights, `w`. I'm trying to use `piecewise` in combination with `switch`, but it isn't working. My code follows

```
function gaussValues1D n = piecewise(n)

switch (n)
    case 1
       w=2; pG=0;
    case 2
       w=[1,1]; pG=[-1/sqrt(3), 1/sqrt(3)];
    case 3
       w=[5/9, 8/9, 5/9]; pG=[-sqrt(3/5), 0, sqrt(3/5)];
    case 4
       w=[(18+sqrt(30))/36,(18+sqrt(30))/36,(18-sqrt(30))/36,(18-sqrt(30))/36]; pG=[sqrt((3/7)-((2/7)*sqrt(6/5))),-sqrt((3/7)-((2/7)*sqrt(6/5))),sqrt((3/7)+((2/7)*sqrt(6/5))),-sqrt((3/7)+((2/7)*sqrt(6/5)))];
    case 5
       w=[128/225,(322+13*sqrt(70))/900,(322+13*sqrt(70))/900,(322-13*sqrt(70))/900,(322-13*sqrt(70))/900]; pG=[0,(1/3)*sqrt(5-2*sqrt(10/7)),-(1/3)*sqrt(5-2*sqrt(10/7)),(1/3)*sqrt(5+2*sqrt(10/7)),-(1/3)*sqrt(5+2*sqrt(10/7))];
    otherwise
        error('No data are defined for this value');
end
```

Comment: "but it isn't working" why? How do you know it isn't working?

Comment: is it because you don't follow function definition rules? `function gaussValues1D n = piecewise(n)` is not valid matlab

Comment: @AnderBiguri I was trying to replicate https://www.educba.com/piecewise-function-in-matlab/, I'd be grateful if you could point me in the right direction

Comment: The right direction is simply to learn what is the correct syntax for matlab functions! This is in the documentation on the first page of google. In general, guessing how code looks like means your guess will be wrong

Comment: You should start here: https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/getting-started-with-matlab.html — avoid learning a new language by following some random website that has illegal MATLAB statements in it. Once you know the basics, you will be able to tell which websites/blogs/tutorials are correct and which are not. In the website you linked, `f x` is likely supposed to be `fx`, a single variable name. But there’s more to that when creating a MATLAB function, so please start with the basics on the link I provided.

Comment: I'll do that. Thanks for the link @CrisLuengo